# Determine if function mutates parameters from signature

Tags: python

In Python it's my understanding that function calls are 'pass by object reference'.  Certain objects are mutable, like lists, and others not, like numbers.  To prevent mutation of the function's input argument, in the case of a list, a shallow copy `l = l2[:]` is made from inside that function.

Is there some method or coding paradigm used to determine if the function mutates the input arguments?  I.e. other then comments?

I ask because in typed languages like C or C++ one can look at the function definition argument types to make this determination.  Specifically, the determination if the function has potential to modify the input argument.

Comment: In C or C++, looking at the variable declarations tells you if the function *can* mutate its input, but that doesn't tell you if in fact it does.

Comment: Generally speaking, if a function mutates an input parameter, then that mutation is the *whole point* of calling the function.  If mutation is simply a side-effect of the functionality, a well-written function would make a copy itself, to avoid screwing up its caller.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's true, but well-written code will only omit `const` when it does in fact modify.

Comment: So the answer is no, there's no programming method for this -- there's no type hints, it's just in the documentation.

Comment: The function’s *documentation* or perhaps the general paradigm used by the library in question usually gives you a hint. If it doesn’t, you can only guess.

Comment: Usually it's pretty obvious. `list.sort()` doesn't return anything, so how else could it work other than by mutating? `sorted()`, OTOH, returns the sorted sequence, and the sequence doesn't even have to be stored (it can be a generator), so it must work by creating a new sequence.

Comment: But there are exceptions. `list1 += list2` might have been specified as `list1 = list1 + list2`, but it's actually implemented as `list1.extend(list2)`.